# How to implement already written python scripts into Celery

Tags: python, redis, celery, scheduled-tasks, flower

I am having a hard time understanding how to refractor already written python scripts into celery. What needs to be changed in the script? I can't find any tutorials on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

My advice - use logic. You notice all examples in Celery documentation contain some sort of task, which is typically a *Python function* (it can be a class too but I see that rarely). So the first thing you should think about is how to wrap your existing code in such a way that it becomes a call to a function with relevant parameters. Once you have that function, decorate it into a Celery task, and you are good to go.